# Determine the convergence/divergence of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried using DCT and LCT, but in both cases the comparison test fails.
Below is the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac {\sin(n)}{n^{0.9}}$$.

Using the absolute convergence test is the first step but from thereon proving that the series is convergent/divergent is tricky. The implementation of the maclaurin series didn't work out either. I would love to know about any other method as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This series is the imaginary part of $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}n^{-a}z^n$ for some real positive $a$ and some complex $z\ne1$ such that $|z|=1$. Does this [ring a bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)?

Comment: So the test suggests that the series is convergent conditionally. Any other methods that come to mind...

Comment: @John What for? This is the One (of course one can disguise it somewhat but the core idea stays roughly the same, I believe).

Comment: I like looking at different methods :). But, I guess you're right. Thanks once again for providing a quick answer :).